# How to Upload Image in Directory and Database in php

Tags: php

I want to Upload imagename into database and directory then want to show it on preview page (preview.php ). but its not working at all. as i am new to programming, so i need support. here the problem is, neither the image save into directory nor into the database.

here is the form page (form5.php) where we select image and after click on submit it goes to next page pptupload.php.

```
<form method="post" action="pptupload.php?appid=<?php echo $appid; ?>" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

                            <table>
                              <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                      <img id="pptimg" src="#" width="600px" height="300px" alt="Scanned Passport" />   
                                      <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
                                   </tr>

                                      <tr>
                                         <input name='but_upload' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save and Continue">
                                      </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                </form>
```

here is the next Page (pptupload.php ) . On this Page, I want redirect to next page preview.php after successful upload of image and if it failed then show error and return back to the image selection page called form5.php .

```
<?php

session_start();

$appid = $_GET['appid'];

include("connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

 $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
 $target_dir = "upload/";
 $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

 // Select file type
 $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

 // Valid file extensions
 $extensions_arr = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif");

 // Check extension
 if( in_array($imageFileType,$extensions_arr) ){

  // Upload file
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target_dir.$name);

 }

}

// Insert record
  $query = "insert into payments(app_id, pptimg) values('$appid','$name')";
  if (mysqli_query($connect,$query)){
    echo "Image were updated successfully.";
    header("Location: preview.php?appid=".$appid);
    }else{
    echo "Photo not uploaded".mysqli_error($connect);
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code :

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It's My pleasure @user8879741 :)

Comment: :-  how to rename the filename if already exist there in directory, want something like if i have uploaded image img.jpg second time it should renamed to img2.jpg, if 3rd time it should img3.jpg and the number should go like this if found image name duplicate.

Comment: Please try this `$actual_name = pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$original_name = $actual_name;
$extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$i = 1;
while(file_exists('tmp/'.$actual_name.".".$extension))
{           
    $actual_name = (string)$original_name.$i;
    $name = $actual_name.".".$extension;
    $i++;
}`

Comment: More Detail : https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/25435844/PHP-upload-file-and-rename-if-already-exist.html